# get entire json string from treestore

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I have a treestore that is added to a gantt chart in extjs.

After i've done some modifications i would like to get the json string back, not just the modified records but the entire string.

the treestore api can be found [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore).

It seems that you can just ask the date from a store but not from a treestore.
Anyone can help?

Comment: What does "the date" have to do with the rest of your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'cascadeBy' on the NodeInterface - check it in the API (it is decorated onto the Model class). For each node, grab the data you want and push it into an array or create a tree structure - whichever you prefer. To encode a full record just do Ext.encode(model.data).